# Mysql table cell doesn't change value on click

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to write a php code that changes the availability of a certain apartment. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <?php 

            $servername = "localhost";
            $username = "bla";
            $password = "blabla";
            $dbname = "testDB";

            // Create connection
            $connect = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

            // Check connection
            if ($connect->connect_error) {
                die("Connection failed: " . $connect->connect_error);
            }else{
                echo "Connected successfully to the database: " . $dbname . "<br><br>";
            }

            $query = "SELECT * FROM test";
            $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

            echo "id: " . $row["id"] . " // Address: " . $row["address"] . " // Rooms: " . $row["rooms"] . " // Availability: " . $row["availability"] . ".<br>";
            ?>
                <form method ="post" action ="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
                    <input name="update" type="submit" value="Change Availability">
                </form>
            <?php

            if(isset($_POST["update"])) {
                $avail =  mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT availability FROM test WHERE id='1'");
                $availCheck = mysqli_fetch_array($avail);
                settype($availCheck, "int");

                if($availCheck == 1){
                    $upAvail = mysqli_query($connect,"UPDATE test SET availability='0' WHERE id='1'");
                }else{
                    $upAvail = mysqli_query($connect,"UPDATE test SET availability='1' WHERE id='1'");
                }
            }

        ?>

    </body>

</html>
```

And this is the output I get:

Connected successfully to the database: testDB

id: 1 // Address: 3787 cote des neiges // Rooms: 2 // Availability: 1.
Change Availability

So here is my issue. When the availability is 1 and I press the button it changes to 0. But after that, when I press the button again, it doesn't change back to 1.

Why is that?

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not toggling the `availability`. The `mysqli_fetch_array` fetches the row from the `test` table matching the id (id=1). As a result, `$availCheck` will always equal `1` after you cast the non-empty array to an integer.

You can replace all that logic with a single `MySQL` query to toggle the value.

```
UPDATE test SET availability = IF(availability = 1, 0, 1) WHERE id=1
```

I think what you wanted to do:

```
 $availCheck = mysqli_fetch_array($avail)['availability'];
```

Comment: Thank you so much @noahnu that solved it! But let me ask you. Is there a way to do the same thing but using my logic? Getting the value of availability on every click, saving it to a variable and then using an if statement to change the value? Just for educational reasons.

Comment: Yes. I edited my answer. See the last code snippet. I'd recommend checking if mysqli_fetch_array is not null/false before attempting to access the associative index.

Comment: Yes, I answered my own question right after I asked you! Thank you so much once again! @noahnu